# Edit a configuration file w/o temp files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a simple script to add some configuration at the top of of the file, and that's how I do this:

```
 #! /bin/bash

 sudo apt-get install monit
 # BELOW IS THE CODE THAT I'M INTERESTING TO CHANGE 
 echo '
 set eventqueue basedir /etc/monit/eventqueue/ slots 1000
 set mmonit http://monit:monit@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/collector
 set httpd port 2812 and use address ec2-xxx.xxx.xx.xx.com 
     allow localhost
     allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
     allow admin:swordfish
 ' | sudo tee -a /etc/monit/monitrc_tmp
sudo cat /etc/monit/monitrc >> /etc/monit/monitrc_tmp
sudo rm /etc/monit/monitrc
sudo mv /etc/monit/monitrc_tmp /etc/monit/monitrc
# UP TO THIS POINT
sudo sed -i 's/set daemon 120/set daemon 20/' /etc/monit/monitrc
exit 0
```

As you can see I 'm trying to add some configuration at the top of the file. And just want to know is there any `flag` or `command` that will help me do this without creating a `tmp` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a case for `sed -i` since you're on Linux.  Also, since this is system administration work, preserve a backup.

```
sudo sed -i.bak -e '1i\
set eventqueue basedir /etc/monit/eventqueue/ slots 1000\
set mmonit http://monit:monit@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/collector\
set httpd port 2812 and use address ec2-xxx.xxx.xx.xx.com\
    allow localhost\
    allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0\
    allow admin:swordfish
' /etc/monit/monitrc
```

This says 'insert the following lines before line 1'...and the lines continue up to and including the one without a backslash at the end.

You can also do the edit of the `set daemon` line too, even though you said it was out-of-scope:

```
sudo sed -i.bak -e '1i\
set eventqueue basedir /etc/monit/eventqueue/ slots 1000\
set mmonit http://monit:monit@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/collector\
set httpd port 2812 and use address ec2-xxx.xxx.xx.xx.com\
    allow localhost\
    allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0\
    allow admin:swordfish
s/set daemon 120/set daemon 20/
' /etc/monit/monitrc
```

Answer (score 2):

This should add the lines to the top of the file.

```
  echo -e " set eventqueue basedir /etc/monit/eventqueue/ slots 1000 \n
  set mmonit http://monit:monit@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/collector \n
  set httpd port 2812 and use address ec2-xxx.xxx.xx.xx.com \n
      allow localhost \n
      allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 \n
      allow admin:swordfish \n 
  $(cat /etc/monit/monitrc)" > /etc/monit/monitrc

 sudo sed -i 's/set daemon 120/set daemon 20/' /etc/monit/monitrc
 exit 0
```